# How do I test my static evaluation function?

Tags: engines, evaluation, chess-ai

I am programming a basic chess AI, within it I have my evaluation function.
It is simple, only uses piece square table values, and does basic calculations for the pawn structure and king safety.

How would I go about testing the accuracy of my static evaluation function, is there a website which hosts a powerful one for me to compare to?

Comment: Given that there is no "right answer" for static evaluation functions, how would you define "accuracy" for a static evaluation function?

Comment: @Allure for example, if my one detects significant white advantage, and the test one does not, that'd be inaccurate.

Comment: What do you mean by that "is there a website which hosts a powerful one for me to compare to?"

Comment: https://hxim.github.io/Stockfish-Evaluation-Guide/ is a full recreation of Stockfish's old hand-crafted static eval with a detailed breakdown for all the evaluation terms.